# Proper way of using generics for composition of elements in java

Tags: java, generics

Tree contains elements of TreeNode with data elements of type T.

I define as below

```
class TreeNode<T>
{
    T data;
}
```

The following dosen't make sense.

```
class Tree<TreeNode<T>>
{
   TreeNode<T> node;
}
```

then ***case 1***

```
class Tree
{
    TreeNode<T> node;
}
```

but above gives error at T in line 3.

then ***case 2***

```
class Tree<N extends TreeNode<T>>
{
   TreeNode<T> node;
}
```

compiler complains at T in line line 1 -  T cannot be resolved.

but below ***case 3*** compiler is happy

```
class Tree<T extends TreeNode<T>>
{
    TreeNode<T> node;
}
```

but the above dosen't make sense. it will be true as in the case like T extends Comparable, but here it says that Tree contains elements of type subtype TreeNode containing data of type T, which inturn is of type T, which says that TreeNode also contain elements of type TreeNode which is not my intention.

What is the right way of defining that Tree contains elements of type TreeNode of data elements T ?
and Tree contains elements of subtype TreeNode ?

Is there any way to tell to the compiler that T is declared in TreeNode class ?

Also how to paramerize TreeNode and Tree saying that TreeNode contains elements of type T and also had pointers for TreeNode left child and right child ?

Comment: What's wrong with `class Tree<T> { TreeNode<T> node; }`?

Comment: yes thanks this will solve the problem,i'm always thinking that Tree contains elements of type TreeNode.